# Is it possible to create a WAR and a JAR of same maven project

Tags: maven, jar, war

I have  maven project which needs to be exposed as a webservice for 3rd party client but same project needs to be used as a JAR between internal modules.

Is this thing possible using different maven profiles in a single pom.

Comment: yes, but better would be to have two modules, one for the client jar and another one for ws, in order to have different type of tests and concerns in each module. Maintenance and project evolution would also benefit from this approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a war and jar from a web project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509893/how-to-create-a-war-and-jar-from-a-web-project)

Comment: This site has a search function. Use it before posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the configuration in the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) via:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After you have configured that way you can use the generated jar file as a usual dependency except for the classifier:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>myVersion</myVersion>
  <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```